# How can I scan a directory, get the ruby files, execute them and get the output?

Tags: ruby

I have no experience in ruby, but I got this task. The specification says I got an argument from command line which is a directory path. I have to scan this dir for ruby files. If I found them, I have to execute and write to file the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a given path `input_dir` then you can change directory to that path, look for any ruby files and then iterate by executing them:

```
input_dir = "/path"

Dir.chdir(input_dir)
search_string = input_dir + "/*.rb"
ruby_files = Dir[search_string]
ruby_files.each do |file|
  system("ruby", file)
end
```