# Running all the scripts in a given directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, and I am trying to figure out a few things. My current problem is this: What is the easiest way to enter a directory (given as a command line argument), run every `.rb` file in the folder, and gather the results. The program should write every result in a format like "filename :: OK" or "filename :: WRONG" depending on the result.

I use `system ("ruby filename.rb")` to run the files, and `Dir.chdir("Folder")` to get in the folder, but I have no idea how to iterate through them, and work them out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755665/get-names-of-all-files-from-a-folder-with-ruby to get a list of the files in a directory. Does that help?

Comment: Must be a homework assignment or something as this has been asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631576/how-can-i-scan-a-directory-get-the-ruby-files-execute-them-and-get-the-output

Comment: @pjd yeah i answered this once and saw 2 other questions like it already

Comment: @locoboy If you can find those other questions, could you link them here so we can close them as duplicates?

Comment: @Ajedi32this is a duplicate of the question that pjd linked to.

Comment: @locoboy Yeah, I was going to vote to close this as a dup of that one, but SO won't let me. (No accepted or upvoted answer on the other question, and I'm not sure I want to upvote the one that's there.) You mentioned there being another question though besides the one that's linked?

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as

```
for file in Dir['./*.rb']
    system('ruby ' + file)
    # return status stored in $? variable
    # files will still output to commandline normally
end
```

Don't recommend running that file as it is ;) Might have infinite loops or something.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it would be best to find my own method, so I stopped looking for help, and finished the task in a relatively short time, so I guess I can close this topic, since there are similar ones. Thanks for the answers guys

Comment: You'll learn, don't let StackExchange get you down :) Google never judges.